# Check for element in AutoFilter before trying to deselect it

Tags: vba, excel

I want to refresh my pivot table as the data within the range it is looking at does change. Then I need to be able to unselect any blanks from the filter.

My code below does this, however if there is not a blank present (In the form of `""` or `(blank)`) then it will throw up an error. 
I guess I need it to check for the presence of these elements in the filter before trying to  hide them...

How do I achieve this?

```
   Dim pt As PivotTable: Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BarSummary")
    pt.RefreshTable
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BarSummary").PivotFields("Shape Codes")
       .PivotItems("").Visible = False
       .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a case where `On Error Resume Next` is simplest:

```
On Error Resume Next
.PivotItems("").Visible = False
.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: Bingo, thanks. I use this elsewhere but it never crossed my mind for this for some reason.